# I have linked the JS file inside the body under the html still this comes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

I have seen similar problems in StackOverflow and they all suggested using `windows.onload` and putting the JS under the HTML but the problem still exists. Sometimes after following some solutions, I get errors like

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND loading json.js

Please help. Thank You.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const toggleButton = document.querySelector('toggle-button')
    const navbar = document.querySelector('navbar')

    toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navbar.target.classlist.toggle('active')
    })
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .navbar {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar.active{
        display: flex;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .toggle-button{
        display: flex;
    }
    .flex{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .navbar ul{
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .navbar li{
        margin-top: 5rem;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar li a{
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .navbar a:after {
        display: none;
    }
    
 }
```

```html
<section class="nav">
    <div class="container flex">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/desktop/logo.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>IMMERSIVE <br> EXPERIENCES <br> THAT DELIVER</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using querySelector you need specify if what your looking for has a class or an id.
in your case since its a class .toggle-button the correct way would be

```
document.querySelector('.toggle-button')
```

but if the target you were looking for had an id with the same name it would be

```
document.querySelector('#toggle-button')
```

also it seems you have done the same to the navbar aswell.. so you will have to change that aswell..

another thing i noticed is that you used classlist prop which I think is possibly wrong instead of classList which should be the correct one.

the .target in `navbar.target.classList.toggle('active')` is unnecessary and will only give u an error since u haven't passed an event into the function. so that is to be changed aswell..

anyways..

### Final Result

the final result will look something like this... it seems to be working but idk if this is the desired result you need...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button')
  const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')

  toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbar.classList.toggle('active')
  })
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .navbar {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.active {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar li {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar li a {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .navbar a:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="nav">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/desktop/logo.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar">y</span>
      <span class="bar">o</span>
      <span class="bar">u</span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>IMMERSIVE <br> EXPERIENCES <br> THAT DELIVER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

im new to coding so if i have made any mistakes sorry and could you point them out aswell? thanks.

Comment: i added 'you' to the 'toggle-button' to make it easier to click as before it was empty in OP's post

Answer (score 0):

`toggle-button` is the classname of the `a` tag, and you should add `.` to indicate class.

```
const toggleButton= document.querySelector('.toggle-button')
                                            ^ add "." here
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define what kind of selector you're accessing. Use this
 `const toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle-button')`.

Find more about querySelector here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp